# Problema com Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE

Tags: php

Estou tento problema ao inserir uma variável dentro de um array...
Dei uma pesquisada aqui e não encontrei nenhuma pergunta parecida que pudesse me ajudar a resolver isso, portanto estou criando essa.

O erro: **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE** aponta para a linha 26

Na linha 26 tenho isso:

```
var $users = array('user1' => $senha);
```

A váriavel $senha que está causando o erro...se eu coloco uma string qualquer funciona sem erro.

Comment: Coloca o resto do código, não dá para ajudar só com uma linha. O erro depende do que está usando.

Comment: essa variável `$senha` foi definida antes, certo?

Comment: E se deixar apenas $users = array('user1' => $senha); sem o var?

Comment: Está dentro de uma classe?

Comment: Deve estar faltando um `;` no final da linha anterior

Comment: Como já dito verifica se esta faltando um ; no final da linha anterior e remove a palavra var

Comment: Qual a versão do php que esta usando?

Comment: Além de remover esse "var", você pode fazer um casting para converter o tipo da senha: $users = array('user1' => (string) $senha);

Answer (score 11, accepted):

O erro **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE** significa que o PHP não estava esperando a definição de uma variável em determinado momento.

Esse erro pode ocorrer em algumas situações, porém sua pergunta engloba alguns casos especiais.

---

O problema mais comum é a ausência de um ponto e vírgula na linha anterior. O interpretador nesses caso informada o erro na linha seguinte que ocorre, e não na linha onde falta o ponto e vírgula:

```
<?php

$var = 1
$var2 = 3;
```

Retorna o erro:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$var2' (T_VARIABLE) in path/file on line 4

---

Outro problema está na definição da palavra `var` antes da variável num contexto fora de uma classe.

Esse palavra chave era utilizada no PHP 4 para definição de propriedades de classes, e atualmente só existe para manter retrocompatibilidade com códigos antigos.

Nas versões recentes, ele é [um sinônimo de `public`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php).

Se está definindo uma variável simplesmente remova o `var`.

```
$users = array('user1' => $senha);
```

---

Agora, se estiver definindo `$user` como propriedade de uma classe, o problema está no fato de não ser possível definir valores dinâmicos diretamente na definição da classe (variáveis ou funções basicamente), como pode [ser observado na documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.properties.php).

```
<?php
class SimpleClass
{
   // declaração de propriedade invalida:
   // ...
   public $var5 = $myVar;

}
```

Isso explica o fato de `var $users = array('user1' => 'Blabla');` funcionar.

**Resumindo**

1. Veja se a linha acima da informado no erro termina com `;`
2. Não use `var` no PHP 5 em diante, prefira [`private`, `protected` ou `public`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php).
3. Se precisa definir valores dinâmicos na propriedade da classe, você pode fazer isso pelo método construtor:

   ```
   <?php
   class SimpleClass
   {

      public $users = array();

      public function __construct($senha){
          $this->users = array('user1' => $senha);

          // ...
      }

   }
   ```

Comment: O uso do var era para php 4, e já está sendo descontinuado.