# Fazer update de um registro com campo único

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Estou usando o [l5-repository](https://github.com/andersao/l5-repository) em meu projeto, mas estou tendo a seguinte dificuldade:

Tenho o código abaixo para fazer com que o *slug* seja único, porém quando vou fazer um update ele diz que o *slug* já existe, quando na verdade é o *slug* do próprio registro que estou editando. Como posso resolver isso?

```
class LandingValidator extends LaravelValidator
{
    protected $rules = [
        ValidatorInterface::RULE_CREATE => [
            'slug' => 'required|unique:landings,slug',
        ],
        ValidatorInterface::RULE_UPDATE => [
            'slug' => 'required|unique:landings,slug',
        ],
   ];
}
```

Tentei desta forma, mas não deu certo:

```
ValidatorInterface::RULE_UPDATE => [
    'slug' => 'required|unique:landings,slug,'.$landing->id,
],
```

> FatalErrorException in LandingValidator.php line 25:
>
> syntax error, unexpected '$landing' (T_VARIABLE)

Answer (score 0):

Acho que seu problema é outro. O erro **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE** significa que o PHP não estava esperando a definição de uma variável em determinado momento.

Confira essa [resposta aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/76073/14865) para ter mais informações sobre esse erro em questão.